# Qt can not slot by name, even after objectName was set

Tags: c++, qt

It occurs when I try to use the Qt auto signal to slot connection using Qt meta object's ability. I try to create a QTimer object, and changed its name, but slot could not match the signal, I don't know why. Here's my code:

mytimer.h:

```
#ifndef MYTIMER_H
#define MYTIMER_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QTimer>

namespace Ui {
class MyTimer;
}

class MyTimer : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MyTimer(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MyTimer();

private:
    Ui::MyTimer *ui;
    QTimer *timer;
private slots:
    void on_timerOne_timeout();
};

#endif // MYTIMER_H
```

mytimer.cpp:

```
#include "mytimer.h"
#include "ui_mytimer.h"
#include <QTimer>
#include <QDebug>

MyTimer::MyTimer(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MyTimer)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    timer = new QTimer(this);
    timer->setObjectName("timerOne");
    // connect(timer, &QTimer::timeout, this, &MyTimer::MySlot);
    timer->start(1000);
}

MyTimer::~MyTimer()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MyTimer::on_timerOne_timeout()
{
    qDebug() << "Timer running...";
}
```

After I changed timer's ObjectName to timerOne, signal-slot-auto-connection :

```
void MyTimer::on_timerOne_timeout()
```

could not run correctly.

using Qt 5.5.0

Comment: Have you tried to rerun qmake?

Comment: Been a long time since I've used Qt, but I'm certain @drescherjm (who deleted his comment) is right.... change the name of the member from `QTimer *timer` to `QTimer *timerOne`.

Comment: I was less certain so I deleted my comment.. In Qt 4.8 and below I have always used the auto connections based on the variable name not the objectName.

Comment: Are you actually calling [`QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetaobject.html#connectSlotsByName) anywhere?

Comment: by using command : qmake -project , but not work, I also change .pro file opetion TEMPLATE to console and app, not work , too. @danielfranca

Comment: @mah after did as you said, the same complain came out :( [ref](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=432590), from the up link, signal sender must be a child object , it seems...not my case. really confused .

Comment: @Oktalist connectSlotsByName member function would be called by uic, see the ui->setupUI(this);, and what's more, if you call this function manually , console complain will came out twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per your comment, [QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetaobject.html#connectSlotsByName) is called by `Ui::MyTimer::setupUi`. But you are calling `setupUi` before constructing the `QTimer`, so there is no child object named `timerOne` when `setupUi` is called, so the auto-connection slot name pattern `on_<object name>_<signal name>` doesn't match any slots.

Move the call to `setupUi` to after the timer has been constructed and given a name:

```
timer = new QTimer(this);
timer->setObjectName("timerOne");
ui->setupUi(this);
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, it is really helpful. if someone else has similar situation like me, just refer to  [Problem with Qts connectSlotsByName](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=432590)  see the #8 Re,  read it and go back, everything is clear.

Comment: Even better: have the member `QTimer timer` instead of `QTimer * timer`. The latter is a premature pessimization - there's no reason whatsoever to manually allocate the timer.

Comment: @KubaOber correct. Remember the timer will still need to have its parent set to `this`, though.

Comment: And that's so that it will be found when `connectSlotsByName` enumerates the object's children. In this case, the parent-child relationship has nothing to do with memory management.